# How to expand absolute positioned wrapper div when using absolute positioned child div?

Tags: html, css

I've searched the site for an answer to this one, and from what I can see, the other questions don't involve the parent `div` using `position:absolute;`

Here is my code:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="child">
    Here are the contents to be displayed.
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#wrapper {width:1024px; height:auto; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; border:solid 1px #000;}

#child {width:500px; height:1000px; position:absolute; top:35px; left:15px; border:solid 1px #FF0000;}
```

Here is a fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aEbFv/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent cant be relative then the child has to be relative (you will obtain the same behavior). If both are absolute then they are not related, and therefor the parent cant adapt to the child (or vice versa). You will also have to add padding-bottom to the parent to patch the full size of the child (at least the top of the child + whatever padding you want)

Updated fiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/aEbFv/8/

```
#wrapper {
    ....
    padding-bottom: 60px; /* 35px from childs top + 25px for padding */
}
#child {
    ....
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the simplest explanation I've read so far.

Answer (score 0):

now give to

```
    #wrapper{
position:relative;
position:absolute; // remove this line
}
    .child{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:500px; // remove this line
    }
```

always give to **parent div** `position relative` and **child div** given `absolute`

More **[about position](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)**

Comment: I tried that on my fiddle, but it didn't make a difference? Also, why would I need to remove the `width` of the child?

Comment: that solution relies on `min-height`, which will not work as the child contents are variable.